# Could not load file or assembly Azure.Core, Version=1.23.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-assembly

I have a .NET 4.8 ASP.NET application and I added Nuget

```
 Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets, 4.3.0.0.
 Azure.Identity, .1.6.0.0.
```

On my build script It copied the dlls to my bin folder but when I debug the code thats using it, it throws an error **Could not load file or assembly  Azure.Core, Version=1.23.0.0**
I checked and I have 1.24.0.0 already referenced. I assume this would work with version 1.24 because the its says on the reference >= 1.23
[image]
[image]

```
Pre-bind state information
LOG: DisplayName = Azure.Core, Version=1.23.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/xxx/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\xxx\bin
Calling assembly : Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\xxx\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Azure.Core, Version=1.23.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/aprimo/d096ca4b/f0bd3501/Azure.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/aprimo/d096ca4b/f0bd3501/Azure.Core/Azure.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/xxxx/bin/Azure.Core.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Anyone have an idea why this is happening.

Comment: Hey @ignition23 I have the same issue right now. I am not used to working such an old version on .NET and can't find out how to fix this. I thought that maybe the nuget package `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets` is too new for .NET 4.8. 
Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Hey ignition23, @russ did you find any solution?

Comment: @ignition23 how’s it going? I tried to remember but when I start work today I will try and find the code. It was a long time ago ⏰

Comment: Thanks @RuSs just let me know if you find the code.

Comment: @Lifewithsun I had a quick look and I m using this reference in the project file. It's mostly not my code so would take me too long to dig into it. But if the following doesn't help then i'll look further:

`<Reference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8, processorArchitecture=MSIL"> <HintPath>..\packages\Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.4.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.dll</HintPath> </Reference>`

and

`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

Comment: @RuSs the reference is already there, in my case build is succeed but while release it throws above error. There might be some setting which is required to avoid the issue. FYI my project is net472 and we build using msbuild.

Comment: @Lifewithsun I had a bit more of a look but, to be honest, I would have to load this code onto my machine which would probably take be most of the day (It's a terrible mess - not my mess) as I remember last time I loaded it, it was a nightmare. Also, sorry, I wish I could remember what I did to get around the problem 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254074/discussion-between-lifewithsun-and-russ).